# storing Stored Procedure Output

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I need to store the output of a stored procedure in #table 
the problem is my procedure's output is a table of 70 field 
so, I can't create the #table before storing the output of the procedure 
because it need alot of effort. 
I need solution similar to `select * into #table from Table_Name` 
witch automatic create the #table

Comment: don't be afraid my friend, we got the answer

Comment: Maybe this can help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829201/sql-select-print-out-results-of-stored-procedue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution at the following link : 
http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=85347
so, to store the output of a stored Procedure we need to use the `OPENROWSET()` function 
but before using it we have to `enable show advanced options` and
 
`Ad Hoc Distributed Queries`  Here is the solution :

```
sp_configure 'show advanced options', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
sp_configure 'Ad Hoc Distributed Queries', 1
RECONFIGURE
GO
Select * into #temp 
from OPENROWSET('SQLOLEDB','Data Source=Myserver;Trusted_Connection=yes;Integrated Security=SSPI', 'Execute DB_Name..Prc')
```

And for the parameters I can add them as string whit procedure revoke statement

```
'Execute DB_Name..Prc'
         + CAST(parameter1 AS varchar(50)) + .....
         + CAST(parameter(n) AS varchar(50))
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you want OPENROWSET. Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx

---

Please note these examples haven't been tested.

```
--Example for master.dbo.sp_who
SELECT * INTO #TempSpWho
FROM OPENROWSET ('SQLOLEDB','Server=(local);
                  TRUSTED_CONNECTION=YES;',
                 'set fmtonly off exec master.dbo.sp_who')
```

Source: http://blogs.technet.com/b/wardpond/archive/2005/08/01/the-openrowset-trick-accessing-stored-procedure-output-in-a-select-statement.aspx

---

Further, if you have parameters to the SP you will need to write dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @testVariable varchar(10);
SET @testVariable = 'varTest';
EXEC( 'SELECT * INTO #TempSpWho
       FROM
       OPENROWSET(
         ''SQLNCLI'',
         ''Database=dbIDsAndNames;Uid=sa;Pwd=nosecurity;'',
         ''SET FMTONLY OFF
         EXEC [dbo].[mySproc] ''' + @testVariable + ''')')
```

Source: http://www.dotnetspider.com/forum/163990-Working-with-Openrowset.aspx

Note: None of the above examples were originally created by me so credit goes to the sources if thy work.

If you are building the temp table manually (ie. not interested in ALL 70 rows) this would be the method:

```
CREATE TABLE #foo(
  [bar] int,
  baz varchar(123)
)
insert into #foo exec spDoSomething
select * from #foo
drop table #foo
```

Comment: No problem; happy you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

The stored procedure must be using some `select * from ..`  statement inside it to generate this output. You can modify that, right?

Comment: yes, but this procedure takes some parameters 
so, the output is different every time I use the proc