# Getting the returned value from a dynamic query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to get the value from executing a dynamic query:

```
declare @query nvarchar(max)
, @returned_value nvarchar(50)

set @returned_value = 'not changed'

set @query = 'select 1000'

exec sp_executesql @query, N'@returned_value varchar(50) OUTPUT', @returned_value OUTPUT 
select @returned_value
```

However, when I select @returned_value I keep getting its initial value.

More precisely:

[image]

How can I keep the returned value? What is happening and what am I missing?

Comment: Not qute same but there is answer inside http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3829201/sql-select-print-out-results-of-stored-procedue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got to assign the parameter in the query.  Replace:

```
set @query = 'select 1000'
```

With:

```
set @query = 'select @returned_value = 1000'
```